# CSS position absolute on 2 relative div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to place an image (logo) on the intersect of 2 divs.

**What I tried:** I put both divs `position: relative;` and logo as `position: absolute;` and logo exists in div (logo is child element of div1).

I also tried to put `z-index` but this also does not work for me.

**Result I am getting:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

```
<body>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        ...1 <!-- div1 -->
        <div style="position: absolute;"><img src="..." alt="..." /></div> <!-- logo -->
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
    ...2 <!-- div2 -->
    </div>
</body>
```

***Edit: logo image not showing above of div2, on div1 logo shows proper as position absolute but hiding half logo behind div2***

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="position: relative;">
    ...1
    <!-- div1 -->
    <div class="logo" style="">Logo</div>
    <!-- logo -->
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative;">
    ...2
    <!-- div2 -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: on div1 logo shows properly as position absolute but hiding half logo behind div2

Comment: Add z-index:1 to .logo img

Comment: Z-index should work i added the background color in my snippet and i see no issue. in this case there is something else causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`transform: translate` *[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)* 
 will be your friend here

```css
#first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}

#second {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="first">
        <div class="logo">
          <img height="50px" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/13/23/05/img-src-x-2310895_960_720.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: on div1 logo shows properly as position absolute but hiding half logo behind div2

Comment: Add z-index:1 to .logo img

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: bordex-box;
}
.div1{
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567042676207-758ced6d805b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center; 
  background-size: cover;
  position:relative;
  height:50vh;
}
.div2{
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742205-e10c9486e506?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center; 
  background-size: cover;
  position:relative;
  height:50vh;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  width:40%;
  height:50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562101660-c49dd4bc0083?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1425&q=80"></div>
<div class="div2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.class_div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 105px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="class_div">
    div 1
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="class_div" style="margin-top:2px">
   div 2
  </div>
</body>
```